# Getting the Count of each array inside a 2D Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a 2D array of colors as described here:

```
var array: [[UIColor]] = [[UIColor.black, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green], [UIColor.gray, UIColor.darkGray, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.red]]
```

and what I'm try to get is the count of both arrays inside the main array.

The purpose....
I'm using a collection view inside my table view cell to display the colors. I've written the code to display only 5 cells (I want a limit of 5 cells) but I'd like the cells to dynamically change the size to conform to the device width.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 5, height: 100)
    }
```

This is the image of the simulator to portray what I'm trying to get across:

[image]

```
extension MyTableViewCell {

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.tag = row
        collectionView.setContentOffset(collectionView.contentOffset, animated:false) // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return array[collectionView.tag].count
    }
```

Comment: Updated my post but I don't seem to be implementing `numberOfSections`

Comment: A collectionView seems like overkill if it's just going to be within a tableView cell, why not just use a UIStackView?

Comment: @clawesome huh, I’ll look into that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `indexPath`'s `section` property and use it as an index to subscript your array and get the number of elements of that section. You will need to coerce it to `CGFloat` to use it as a divisor:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   .init(width: view.frame.width / CGFloat(array[indexPath.section].count), height: 100)
}
```

---

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { array[section].count  }
```

---

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { array.count }
```

---

In your viewDidLoad:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

---

Don't forget to invalidate your layout on device rotation:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to work but only for the first array. By what I mean, the first array contains 3 colors, and creates no blank space. Which is exactly what Im looking for but when it comes to the second array that contains 4 colors, it creates the extra cell outside of the view.

Comment: show your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` implementation

Comment: you need to return `array[section].count` as well

Comment: Updated the post with the `numberOfItemsInSection` on my post and returned the `array[section].count` but that doesn't seem to work either. I may just have to rethink how I display my colors.

Comment: @JoshMyrwold https://www.dropbox.com/s/bou3elx2093o5wq/Color%20Collection.zip?dl=1

Comment: thank you! I appreciate the quick and thorough response

Comment: Hey there, still really appreciate your help. I was wondering if there was any way to display the ```array[section]``` inside a ```UITableViewCell```?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map` function for this.

Disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested

```
let countedArray: [Int] = array.map { $0.count }
```